# Python pip install SSLError bad handshake

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install various python packages on Windows 10. I have anaconda installed, and have not been able to install packages not included in conda until now, because of lack of admin rights. I have python version 3.6.3 installed. I have OpenSSl version 1.0.2.k 26 Jan 2017.

I am working from a python console inside JetBrains Pycharm.

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','Plotly'])
```

The result:

```
Collecting Plotly
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/plotly/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/plotly/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/plotly/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/plotly/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/plotly/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Plotly (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Plotly
```

I get the exact same errors if I try to install a package that doesnt exist (fsldkjfs). If I try to install a package already installed, I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages
```

I did have a popup related to certificates earlier today,but can remeber verbatum what the message was

Answer (score 0):

Open your anaconda prompt folder and right click on the anaconda prompt, select DefendPoint administrator and open it that way, you will maybe then be able to install your packages.